# Showing iframe element in Django admin view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to add a simple view to Django's admin site, like so

```
# collection_management/admin.py

    class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    ...

    def plasmid_map_view(self, request):
        return render(request, 'admin/collection_management/plasmid_map.html')
    ...
```

It uses a template, which contains an iframe element that loads an external url

```
# templates/admin/collection_management/plasmid_map.html

...

{% block content %}<div id="content-main">
<iframe 
style="height: 80vh; width: 100%; resize: both; overflow: auto; border:None;"
src="​https://designer.genomecompiler.com/plasmid_iframe?file_url=http://s3.amazonaws.com/gcc_production/plasmid_viewer/OG34_OG34_pSF-OXB19.gb​">
</iframe>
</div>
{% endblock %}

...
```

When I try to load the page, I get a strange behaviour whereby Django prepends the "root" url of my site (example.net:8443) to the address that should be opened inside the iframe, which obviously does not exist

`https://example.net:8443/collection_management/plasmid_map/%E2%80%8Bhttps:/designer.genomecompiler.com/plasmid_iframe?file_url=http://s3.amazonaws.com/gcc_production/plasmid_viewer/OG34_OG34_pSF-OXB19.gb%E2%80%8B`

[image]

How can I prevent Django from doing that?

Comment: Double-check your `src` attribute in the template - I think you have some characters in front of the `https://` which are causing the browser to treat it as a relative URL. Django would not modify that URL (you can verify by looking at the generated source).

Comment: This was indeed the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some hidden characters flanking the src string